# Where has hSetEncoding gone?

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, io

I was fairly sure that a while back GHC added the ability to explicitly set the character encoding on a `Handle`. However, when I look in `System.IO`, I don't see anything relating to character encodings. (I have Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0)

Am I blind, or simply mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated where the function is hiding.

**Summary:** Make sure to use `System.IO` from package base, not from package haskell2010.

**Details:** Hoogle tells me that there is [`System.IO.hSetEncoding`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3ahSetEncoding) in the latest **base** package.

- http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=hSetEncoding

Checking the documentation about the Haskell platform 2012.4.0.0, I see a `System.IO` module from the `haskell2010` package. And that module doesn't seem to contain `hSetEncoding`.

- http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/2012.4.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.0.1/System-IO.html

But do not despair, there seems to also be the `System.IO` from base which contains `hSetEncoding`.

- http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/2012.4.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/System-IO.html#v:hSetEncoding

So I guess you just have to make sure that you use the `System.IO` from base and not from haskell2010.

Answer (score 1):

*Oh my God!*

OK, I just figured this out.

1. It appears that there are *two* packages that both export `System.IO` - the `base` package and the `haskell2010` package.
2. The two versions of the module are *different*. Specifically, only the module from `base` has all the character encoding stuff in it.
3. When you go to the locally-installed module index, it only shows you the version of `System.IO` that's included in `haskell2010` - without all the character encoding stuff.

It appears the only way to see the version from `base` is to click on some other module exported from `base`, then click "Contents", then navigate to `System.IO` from there. *Then* it shows you the correct module!

Counter-intuitive, much? o_O

OK, so I've found my function now, but man, Haddock should probably do a better job of handling this obscure edge-case...

Comment: Hmm, _my_ locally-installed module index lists the `base` versions. If the platform's index lists the `haskellXY` versions, I think you should tell the platform maintainers that that is a suboptimal choice.